# Ways to reach the start city using n trips

Tags: java, algorithm

In some programming contest, I saw this question:

> A person wants to travel some cities and come back to the city where
>   he/she started. Total 5 cities are present and each city is connected
>   to its adjacent city i.e.: c1 - c2, c2 - c3, c3 - c4, c4 - c5, c5 -
>   c1. The person will start the journey from city 1.  Also, the person
>   has some limited number of trips to use for traveling. Traveling from one city to another costs him/her 1 trip. We need to find the
>   total number of ways a person can travel the given cities and come
>   back to city 1 using the allocated number of trips.

```
Example: 

Input: 4
(means 4 trips are allowed)
Output: 6
(As the output can be large, so it should be modulo 10^9+7)
the possible ways are: 
1-2-1-2-1
1-2-1-5-1
1-5-1-2-1
1-5-1-5-1
1-2-3-2-1
1-5-4-5-1
```

If the question has limits on the number of trips to be less than 10^9 then its easy to solve as the problem has optimal substructure and overlapping subproblems. But the constraint given was 1<=n<=10^18. I couldn't initialize an array with a dimension that long, so couldn't apply dp. Please help me on how to solve this using dp. Or is this question just a permutation or combinations type of question?
Thanks.

Comment: If the cities are not in a circle it would be just all movements to left and right with an equal amount of left and right. But the cities are in a circle. Therefor the number of left- and right-movements can differ by a multiple of one walk through the circle. I think the rest is "simple" mathematics.

Comment: Did you have any idea to start with ? Or do you expect us to do it for you ? If you are completely stuck, you might need to ask your teacher/tutor some help first.

Comment: @AxelH I just had the idea of dp first. Then I thought it might be a permutation problem, but couldn't manage much on my own. If the problem seems too simple, may be I should try again then.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

1. Store the number of ways to reach each city in a vector
2. Work out a matrix that allows you to update this vector by 1 step
3. Raise the matrix to the power n using binary exponentiation
4. Multiple this power matrix by the starting vector (1,0,0,0,0)
5. Read off in entry 1 the number of ways to reach city 1 after n steps

Answer (score 0):

(edit)

Sorry read your question a bit too fast.

If all cities are connected then this is a simple permutation problem.

If not you can see it as a graph problem and solve it with an extended breadth first search that caps off as soon as you have reached the limit of possible trips.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is purely mathematical; the answer is a mathematical formula which, once computed on paper, you just plot in your program.

You can reach the initial point either by going back and forth (requiring a multiple of 2 steps), or by doing complete circles(requiring a multiple of 5 steps). Thus you need to check the divisibility of n with 2 and 5, or, to put it in a mathematical form, check if `n=2*k` or `n=5*q`. We will compute the number of paths independently for the 2 cases, but if n is divisible with both 2 and 5, we will add the two results (since n steps can be done in both ways, either as a multiple of 2 or multiple of 5).

If `n=5*q`, we will do our n steps as q cycles of 5 steps. Each cycle can be in either direction, clockwise or counter clockwise. For the first cycle, there are 2 possibilities (the 2 directions), for the second cycle, another 2 possibilities, independent of the previous cycle, and so on. Thus, the number of paths is 2*2*2... = **2<sup>q</sup>** .

If `n=2*k`, we will do our n steps as k back-and-forth paths (one step forward, one step backward). For each of these k paths, there are two directions to go, thus, for k closed-paths, there are **2<sup>k</sup>** paths.

Note: I have given the name back-and-forth path, or closed path, for paths such as 1-2-1. Actually, from the graph theory perspective, they are cycles too, but i did not name them cycles as not to confound them with the 1-2-3-4-5-1 cycles.

The above computation, however, does not take into account the paths such as 1-2-3-2-1, but only 1-2-1-2-1, or 1-2-1-5-1. I am still working on that> I will post this answer the way it is right now as to give inspiration on how the computation might look like.

Another aspect to take into account is the number of ways we could write n as 2*a + 5*b, giving 2<sup>a</sup> * 5<sup>b</sup> paths. I think `n=2*a+5*b` is a dyophantic equation.